# Opening .txt file in Python as Json file

Tags: python, json

I've searched Stackoverflow for a whole day, however I can't seem to find the answer to my problem. I also tried several things, but it did not work; I don't think the solution is very hard though, so maybe one of you can help me.

The .txt file is the following format:

```
{"text": "x x x x"}
{"text": "x x x x"}
{"text": "x x x x"}
```

It should be the following code:

```
with open("/Python map/Jsons scraped.txt") as jsonfile:    
          test2 = json.load(jsonfile)
```

However this leads to the following error (UnsupportedOperation: not readable)

I also tried adding 'w', 'r', 'a+', and other reading forms:

```
with open("/Python map/Jsons scraped.txt") as jsonfile:    
          test2 = json.load(jsonfile, 'w')
```

This leads to the following errors. With adding 'w' the error is still "UnsupportedOperation: not readable". However, with using 'r' instead of 'w', the error becomes "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value".

Does someone know what I can do?

Comment: The string that you are trying to convert is not a valid json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is your JSON file format is wrong. it should be like this

```
[{"text": "x x x x"},
 {"text": "x x x x"},
 {"text": "x x x x"}]
```

Please notice I have added square bracket([]) at first and the last position also I added comma (,) after each JSON object

after that below, py code can help you reading JSON file

```
import json

f = open('json.txt', )
data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the format of my json file, that was indeed the main problem. After setting encoding to 'utf-8' I was able to retrieve the json objects in python.

Answer (score 1):

Try that out:

```
import json

with open('hello world/smth.txt', 'r+') as f:
    print(json.load(f))
```

when you add slash at the beginning of the path, it looks by absolute path, try to remove it or use like:

```
'./hello world/smth.txt'
```

moreover, you are using not valid json, I would move by each line and convert it to json, like:

```
import json

with open('hello world/smth.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [json.loads(x) for x in f.readlines()]

print(result)
```